# need to understand infinitive

Tags: english, verbs, grammar, korean, infinitive

What is the easiest way to understand what an infinitive is?
How do I know which verb in which sentence is an infinitive?
For example, let us take this website:
[Infinitive](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/infinitive_form.htm)
This is the example I am interested in:

1. I need to run every day.   (The infinitive form with the word *to* is
   called the full infinitive or *to*-infinitive.)
2. I must run every day.   (After certain verbs, the *to* is dropped
   (more on this below).)
3. I run every day.   (This is not in the infinitive form. This is a
   finite verb, i.e., a verb functioning as the main verb.)

How do I differentiate between example 2 and example 3?
How do I know 3 is not an infinitive but 2 is ?
If 2 had been *I must run to school every day* would that make it a non-infinitive?

This is probably a completely different question, but I will put it here anyway.
When comparing with other languages, if it says *infinitive*, should I consider it to have the same meaning as the English infinitive, or can it have a different meaning, according to the language?

Let us take  the example of Korean. [This Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_verbs) has an entry for infinitives in Korean. If I understood correctly, "infinitive" is the form of the verb that is unchanged according to tense, voice or anything similar. (So *watch* may be an infinitive but *watched* is not). In Korean, the unchanged form of a verb is called **root** (example, *watch* = 보다). This root changes form (prefixes, suffixes etc, based on negation, formality, tense, etc). Can this root be called an infinitive as well? (in my opinion, probably not, as the explanations in the wikipedia page I linked seems to use root and infinitive as different entities, but how do I explain the difference)?

Comment: Substitute *I* with *he*. "He must run every day" vs. "He runs every day". In the second case, you had to inflect the verb, thus it can't be the infinitive.

Comment: so in case 3, when changing the sentence from first to second person, the verb has to change it's form, so it is not an infinitive. Is this how I should interprete it?

Comment: Interestingly, Latin infinitives have voice and tense/aspect marking: *laudare* (oresent active), *laudari* (present passive), *laudavisse* (perfect active), *laudatus esse* (perfect passive), *laudaturus esse* (future active) and *laudatum iri* (future passive).

Comment: in this case simple: the first two sentences use 'run' with an auxiliary verb, the third doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Infinitives are rather different in different languages, and some languages, like Bulgarian, don't have infinitives at all. In some languages infinitives have a special suffix and are easily recognized, e. g. in Russian the most typical infinitival suffix is -ть, like in писать 'to write', читать 'to read', etc.

In English the infinitives are in most cases marked by the infinitival particle 'to' (to-infinitive), but sometimes they are not (bare infinitive), still the list of cases when they are not mark is pretty short. The English unmarked infinitives follow another verb. Here is the list of the verbs that are always followed by an unmarked infinitive, infinitives are marked in **bold**:

1. The nine defective verbs: can, could, shall, should, will, would, may, might, must: *I cannot **do** that.*
2. The verb 'let': *Let me **help** you.*
3. The verb 'help': *He helps me **do** my homework.* (Nowadays many use the to-infinitive after 'help'.)
4. The verb 'make' in the meaning 'to cause': *He made me **cry**.*
5. The verb 'do' (Past 'did') used to form questions, negative sentences, and emphatic sentences in the Present Simple Tense and in the Past Simple Tense: *Do you **know** him*? (question), *I don't **know** him.* (negative), *I do **know** him!* (emphatic);
6. After 'needn't', 'need not' and questions with 'need [subject]': *You needn't **go** there.*

Unlike many languages, [the English infinitive has different forms](http://www.grammaring.com/the-forms-of-the-infinitive), 4 for an intransitive verb (they don't have Passive forms), and 8 for a transitive one. English infinitives can change for voice (Active: *to write,* Passive: *to be written*), for aspect (Non-Continuous: *to write*, Continuous: *to be writing*), for perfectness (Non-Perfect: *to write*, Perfect: *to have written*), and there are Perfect-Continuous infinitives: *to have been writing*. So, you got it wrong, the infinitives *can* change after the grammar categories.

Comment: I must say I find it rather odd that #3 implies *help **to** [verb]* is more likely "nowadays". I've no idea what the actual usage and trends have been over time for that specific verb, but it seems to me ***to*** was once more common in #4 (*"He maketh me to lie down in green pastures"*, and all that). That's to say, if there'e a "general trend", I think it's towards discarding ***to*** in more and more contexts. Btw - there's also *"He **gave** me to understand"*, but I maybe that's not quite the same construction.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - There wasn't anything about diachrony in the OP, so I described the state of things now, and I understand 'now' as the last 50-70 years, that's the generations that are living now. The only tendency about infinitives I know of is the increasing usage of to-infinitives after 'help'. If you, or anyone else, know of other tendencies, please, write about them here, that's quite interesting.

Comment: IANAL (I am not a **linguist!** :), so you must take anything I say with a *huge* [gram of salt.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22taken+with+a+gram+of+salt%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22taken+with+a+gram+of+salt%22&tbm=bks) ("huge gram"? Nah, that doesn't quite work!) Anyway, I might do a bit of sleuthing on NGrams/Google Books to see if I can find evidence of any tendencies in this area. My instinct is to think there ought to be a *general* trend - but English being what it is, perhaps different trends apply to different verbs.

Comment: The linked page gives four active and four passive forms; are there two more active forms they didn't list?

Comment: @supercat - What forms? There are no other forms of the English infinitive, than those that are listed in the linked page.

Comment: #6 is not quite right. It would be more accurate to say unmarked infinitives follow the verb _need_ outside affirmative declaratory contexts when _do_-support is not employed – or in layman’s terms, after _needn’t_, _need not_ and questions with _need [subject]_. Also supercat is right: you say transitive verbs have 6 infinitival forms, which should be 8 (the continuous passives are left out).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - The forms like ‘to be being written’ (continuous passive) and ‘to have been being written’  (perfect continuous passive) exist only _theoretically_, in fact they are not used since the situations where they'd be needed are practically nonexistent.

Comment: @YellowSky That is absolutely not true. They are rare, but they are used when the situation calls for it. An example of the former can be found in one of the Harry Potter books where “he didn’t have a clue what was going on, but he didn’t seem **to be being expelled**”; and I am quite sure I read an example of the latter just a few days ago in an article, something along the lines of “we have argued most of the literature generally assumed **to have been being written** under Jón’s stewardship was in fact written later”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I have no reason to doubt your statement, I've corrected 6 to 8. In fact, the linked page does have the 8 forms, I wonder why I have it as “6”, perhaps a typo, I've edited the answer. Still, I can's see how supercat is right: _they_ did list the 8 forms, it was me who miscalculated them.

Comment: Re: "The only tendency about infinitives I know of is the increasing usage of to-infinitives after 'help'." - this is not what numerous corpus studies have shown. There are tons of research on this, you could start with Callies 2013 *Bare infinitival complements in Present-Day English* https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139060998.011 or Lohmann 2011 *Help vs help to: a multifactorial, mixed-effects account of infinitive marker omission* https://doi.org/10.1017/S1360674311000141 @FumbleFingers you might find this interesting too

Comment: @AlexB.: Thanks for the links. It's just taken me 10 minutes to get back into the swing of thinking about this one, and all I'm "reasonably confident" about so far is that I still think there's something wrong with talking about *the increasing usage of to-infinitives after 'help'*. I'm a bit tied up now, so I'll leave it until tomorrow to follow (and hopefully grok! :) your links.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Considering a pun--Ger. inf. *?Nutz-ziehen* for *nutzen* "use" w. r. t. the idiom *Nutzen ziehen* 'enjoy fruit (of labour)'--the implied shift of stress should be hilarious. This need said if the onset *z-* could assimilate the stem's coda. It is remarkable on semantic grounds that *nutzlos* "useless", *need to* and *benötigt* "needed" are formally incompatible, but I suggest the pun recovers leveling that can show the forms possibly related: the *to* from before to-infinitive. Albeit as so often I won't manage writing a research brief in 512 characters.

Comment: @YellowSky the purely synchronic view is baneful while the diachrony should be extremely interesting in comparison with all related languages. For example, *he gave me to understand* sounds like *zu verstehen geben*, *zu bedenken geben*, etc. A difficult case would be *admit to*, German *zugeben* "admit", besides *zu geben* "add to", *Zugabe* "encore". Also, *be-* which is rather akin to *by* and maybe with instr. \*-bhi might be framed as participles instead, cp. passivising *Der zu Beurteilende* "the to be judged (one)", *das bekömmliche Essen* "the comely food", *to become* ~ *befit, suit*

Answer (score 4):

To answer the last question first, ***Infinitive*** is a term from Latin grammar.
It refers in Latin to one of several tenseless verb forms.

Etymologically, *infinitive* means 'unending' (just like *infinite*); here the reference is to lack of tense.
In other languages, *infinitive* is often used to describe one, or more, untensed verb forms.
[The Latin terms](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/wow/grammar.latin.html) *Participle, Gerund,* and *Gerundive* are also in use for untensed verb forms.
What these terms mean, in each language, has to be determined individually. There is no consistency.

The rest of the question is about **English** infinitives, and here the trick is knowing
that there are **two** different meanings for *infinitive* in English grammar.
If you keep them straight, you won't be easily confused.

1. ***Infinitive*** can refer to the infinitive **form** of the verb, e.g, *be, run, go, see, feel, have, admit, ask*
   Every verb in English (except defective verbs like *born* and modal auxiliaries) has

- **Three Principal Parts**: ***be**, was, been; **run**, ran, run; **go**, went, gone; **see**, saw, seen;*
  ***feel**, felt, felt; **have**, had, had; **admit**, admitted, admitted; **ask**, asked, asked.*
  These three verb forms are called, in order, the ***Infinitive***, the Past, and the Past Participle.

2. ***Infinitive*** can also refer to infinitive **clauses** of various kinds, which are subordinate clauses
   that use infinitive verb forms, instead of present, past, or participial forms.

- ***For him to err** is human ~ He wants **to leave** early ~ She's the one **to see** about that.*
  These are normally marked with the [*for...to* complementizer](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/Complements.pdf), though the *for* that
  marks the subject of the clause is frequently absent, along with the subject itself.

As @YellowSky has pointed out, most infinitive clauses are governed by the matrix predicate.
There are a number of auxiliaries that must be followed in construction by an infinitive verb form.

All the modal auxiliary verbs (including the NPI semimodals *need* and *dare*,
as well as the periphrastic modals like *hafta, wanna, oughta, able to,* and *need to*)
must be followed immediately by an infinitive verb form, and the same is true of *do*
in its  *Do*-Support and Emphatic senses.

- ***Do** you **like** ice cream?* but not **Do you liking/liked ice cream?*
- *I **did** take it out!* but not **I did taking/took it out.*

These infinitive verb forms are part of a verb phrase and don't use the complementizer *to*, because they don't introduce complements, just the next verb in a verb chain.
See the [Verb Phrase Guide](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/VPguide.pdf) for details.

Executive Summary:

> Infinitive clauses are very complex, and they use infinitive verb forms.
> Infinitive verb forms are used in infinitive clauses (usually marked by *to*);
> infinitive verb forms also occur with auxiliary verbs in verb phrase constructions
> (usually without *to*).

Comment: Isn't **born** 1. the Past Participle of the verb *bear, bore, born*; 2. adjective 'existing as a result of birth'?

Comment: Yes, both. But when not referring to the mother, it's always passive in form; i.e, there is no English verb to indicate birth circumstances except _be born_ (unlike Spanish _nació_, an active verb form); this is rather like the fact that there is no English verb meaning _be named_ (like German _heisst_, an active verb form). In both cases, the construction is effectively defective.

Comment: Well, the child is born (by her mother) - naturally, it's passive. But the mother bore children - naturally, it's active.

Comment: In that case, one uses the spelling _is borne (by)_. This is a true passive, with a direct object promoted to subject and an agent subject demoted to chômeur status. _Born_ without the E is only used in the deponent construction, without agent.

Comment: Hi John, I was wondering if you could help me. I remember somewhere reading a paper (well-known, I believe) arguing that, syntactically, the English auxiliary *do* belonged with the modal verbs, not with the aspectual auxiliaries *have* and *be*. I don't suppose you know who wrote that paper, by any chance?

Comment: Sounds like Chomsky; it's easy to see why - infinitive, first auxiliary, inverts, contracts. But it inflects, so it's not a total match. Plus it's conditioned by syntax and has no meaning, whereas modals are overstuffed with meaning.

Comment: I like the structure of this, but the *for ... to* complementizer as sole example of the subordinate clauses is a surprise. On another note, prior comments of yours about to-infinitives *versus* ing-forms had left quite an impression on me. I would like to read more about it. It is difficult distinguishing participle from gerund, more so if *-ing* continued older *-en* infinitives in part: There is so much precedent for *-in'*. Theres no telling how old this is, is there? I mean -en infinitives trivially nominalize in German, -ung tends to be resultative and Norse has indef. -en nouns